# What is difference between Dark Mode and Dark Theme for any website and application?

Tags: themes, darkmode, ios-darkmode, android-dark-theme, android-darkmode

I am new in UI development, I was asked above question in the interview.
I got confuse because as per my understanding there is no difference. Kindly guide me is there is any difference.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen that Dark Theme and Dark Mode have been used interchangeably on several occasions.
But this article [Browse in Dark mode or Dark theme](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/9275525?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop) by Google Chrome states that

> Note: This feature is called `Dark mode on Desktop` and `Dark theme on mobile devices`.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Not able to get the difference from the URL.

Comment: according to it, dark mode is for desktops and themes are for mobile devices

Answer (score 0):

The themes can be dark or light based on accessibility options and works primarily on web applications or mobile applications.

The dark mode is there to save the electricity and works on operating systems either on windows or Phone or Tablet.

> In order to support accessibility, we do use accessibility mode turn
> on which eventually make it dark.